# How to improve listings display of JSON files?

Tags: listings, punctuation, json

I was wondering if there is a good way for JSON files to be listed with the `listings` package.

The only language definition I could come up with, is this:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{json}
{
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[d]'
}
```

Now, this highlights the strings used in JSON files, but the important syntactical things in JSON are the curly braces, the square brackets, commas, and colons. I have sadly no Idea how I could make them be highlighted in a different manner. I tried adding `{` and `}` as identifier or as keywords, but it didn't work.

I'd really like to make listed JSON files appear nicer, since on a project I need to document I'd really need it. Also, I couldn't find a JSON definition for that on the internet, anywhere else.

On a more general thought: can I highlight all numerals with listings?

Comment: the full json definition is on the page http://www.json.org/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, I know that, but I still don't know how to construct a language definition for listings. Symbols such as `{` are not accepted as keywords. Or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I updated my answer; I initially overlooked the numerals issue; now I've added it to my answer.

Comment: both single- and double-quoted strings should probably have the `[b]` type as they are backslash-escaped in JSON (and Javascript).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Here's one possibility for the colon, comma, braces, square brackets, and numbers, using the `literate` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bera}% optional: just to have a nice mono-spaced font
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
     *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
      {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
      {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
      {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
      {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
      {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
      {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
      {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
      {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
      {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
      {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
      {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
      {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
      {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
      {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
      {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=json,firstnumber=1]
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
0123456789
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One issue is that in a number-alphabet combination (such as a web address), the numbers also get highlighted in the same manner as standalone numbers, while alphabets don't get highlighted, which makes it a little bit weird.

Comment: Another issue is that string literals don't behave as such; for instance, if I have a { inside a string literal, it's also marked up. My example is {   "fmt": "CREATE %{persistence}s TABLE %{identity}D
            %{if_not_exists}s (%{table_elements:, }s) 
            %{inherits}s %{on_commit}s %{tablespace}s" }

Comment: @XiangJi `morestring=[b]"` after the last `literate`, i.e. after `{]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},` treats everything within double quotes as a String, overwriting the literate-behaviour for numbers. You might have to also define a `stringstyle` in order to get a consistent layout for your listing.

Answer (score 17):

Here is an alternate solution which isn't always accurate but if your JSON is formatted "the usual way" it gives quite nice results and colors attributes different from values.

```
\usepackage{bera}% optional: just to have a nice mono-spaced font
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{eclipseStrings}{RGB}{42,0.0,255}
\definecolor{eclipseKeywords}{RGB}{127,0,85}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{eclipseStrings}, % style of comment
    stringstyle=\color{eclipseKeywords}, % style of strings
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray}, %only if you like
    string=[s]{"}{"},
    comment=[l]{:\ "},
    morecomment=[l]{:"},
    literate=
        *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
         {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
         {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
         {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
         {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
         {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
         {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
         {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
         {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
         {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this version fixed some errors I get with the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you! I like the color pallete you defined.