# Getting more context about a a latex error

Tags: beamer, errors

I'm trying to run Beamer to get a listing in a presentation.
I'm getting a mysterious error message that looks like:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               \let 
l.221 \end{frame}

? H
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
 look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Part of my problem is that \let is not in my code, this must be the expansion of a macro.  My immediate question is "How can I get TeX to give me information about what macros it was expanding when it encountered the error?"  That might give me a clue about what to do next.

More context:
I'm trying to use an algorithm listing of json objects in Beamer.

I have the following defined in my header:

```
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{Example}
%--------------------------------------------
%JSON listing mode, from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83085/how-to-improve-listings-display-of-json-files#83100

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
  basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=lines,
  backgroundcolor=\color{background},
  literate=
   *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
    {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
    {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
    {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
    {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
    {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
    {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
    {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
    {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
    {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
    {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
    {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
    {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
    {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
    {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
    {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}
```

The code for the frame in the Beamer file is:

```
\begin{frame}{Proc4 Messages}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{algorithm}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=json]
      {
        app:"ecd://coe.fsu.edu/EPLS/AssessmentName",
        uid:"Student/User ID",
        timestamp:"Time at which event occurred",
        verb:"Action Keyword",
        object:"Object Keyword",
        data:{
          field1:"Value",
          field2:["list","of","values"],
          field3:{part1:"complex",part2:"object"}
        }
      }
  \end{lstlisting}
      \end{algorithm}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
       \item Application header defines vocabulary used in other
          fields.
       \item ...
        \item Data field can hold any number/kind of object.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

The same listing runs fine in another document that uses article rather than beamer style, and the rest of the frame is pretty standard.

Comment: In general, an `lstlisting` should not be placed inside an `algorithm` if that `algorithm` is a float, since `lstlisting` provides its own floating behaviour.

Comment: Please provide us with a *single* document that produces the error. Otherwise there is a danger that additional issues arise from incorrectly patching together these fragments.

Comment: `\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Proc4 Messages}` is the right way. I can't see the need for the `algorithm` environment.

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{xcolor}` with beamer and there is not enough room on a slide to fit in two columns of `0.5\textwidth` because there is some space between the columns. Either make your columns a bit smaller or use `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]`

Comment: as per your question itself, put `\errorcontextlines5` on a line in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks.  Useful to know next time I have such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be related to another issue found in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981008/latex-issue-with-beamer-and-listings

If I change `\begin{frame}{title...}` to `\begin{frame}[containsverbatim]{title...}` it works as expected.

Comment: Please don't use `containsverbatim`: it's only still there for compatibility. You want `fragile`