# Change width of \lstlisting resulting from user defined \lstdefinelanguage

Tags: listings

I used the \lstdefinelanguage to create a formatting for some JSON blocks I'd like to add to my file, I used the one in the answer for this question:

[How to improve listings display of JSON files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83085/how-to-improve-listings-display-of-json-files)

So I created my own \lstdefinelanguage like so:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
     *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
      {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
      {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
      {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
      {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
      {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
      {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
      {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
      {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
      {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
      {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
      {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
      {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
      {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
      {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
      {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}
```

And used it like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=json][firstnumber=1]
    {
      "type": "auth-request",
      "content": {
        "user": "agentA1",
        "pw": "1"
      }
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Example of an AUTH-REQUEST message.}
    \label{fig:auth-request}
\end{figure}
```

This gives the following document:

[image]

So for my question, what is the best way to change the width of this listing? I'd like to make it something like 80% of the `\textwidth` if possible. But if I do this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=json][firstnumber=1, linewidth=.8\textwidth]
        {
          "type": "auth-request",
          "content": {
            "user": "agentA1",
            "pw": "1"
          }
        }
 \end{lstlisting}
```

I get a warning, namely: `Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing`. and it doesn't actually change the look of the listing in the document.

So how do I change the width of a specific listing?

Comment: Does it work if you combine the two pairs of brackets into one optional argument, i.e. `\begin{lstlisting}[language=json,firstnumber=1, linewidth=.8\textwidth]`?

Comment: It appears to be tricky to centre the listings box. It didn't work for me with `figure`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5818/35864

Comment: It does indeed lower the width, but centering it is tricky. I tried the solution from the question you sent but that seems to move the entire listing to the right instead of centering it.

Comment: @moewe use tcolorbox and its listings library. It is easy there to change the width and to enlarge e.g. the left bounding box or to center.