# Change font only used in listing and not in rest of document

Tags: fonts, listings

I created a \lstdefinelanguage command for some JSON blocks I'd like to add into my document, I followed the answer to this question:

[How to improve listings display of JSON files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83085/how-to-improve-listings-display-of-json-files)

In the answer the answerer defines the language like so:

```
\usepackage{bera}% optional: just to have a nice mono-spaced font
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
     *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
      {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
      {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
      {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
      {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
      {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
      {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
      {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
      {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
      {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
      {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
      {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
      {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
      {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
      {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
      {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}
```

The answerer uses the bera font, which makes the JSON look far more visually appealing. I'd like to copy this. The only problem is that when I add the `\usepackage{bera}` command all the text in my entire document is changed to this font, which I don't want. I only want the bera font to be used when I create a listing using the JSON language. What is the best way to do this?

UPDATE:

When I try `\usepackage{beramono}` as suggested by @Davislor I get this output:

[image]

The output I'd like looks like this, which I get when I use `\usepackage{bera}`:

[image]

EDIT 2 MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pdf]{article}

% \usepackage{bera}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
     *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
      {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
      {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
      {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
      {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
      {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
      {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
      {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
      {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
      {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
      {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
      {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
      {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
      {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
      {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
      {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=json]
    {
      "type": "request-action",
      "content": {
        "id": 2,
        "time": 1556636930397,
        "deadline": 1556636934400,
        "step": 27,
        "percept": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Example of a REQUEST-ACTION message.}
    \label{fig:request-action}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might try `\usepackage{beramono}`, which sets only `\ttfamily`, possibly `\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{beramono}` if you want it slightly bigger or smaller. You could also use DejaVu Sans Mono, which is another fork of Bitstream Vera Mono.

Comment: Beramono seems to be different than bera. I show the difference in my updated question.

Comment: You don’t give a MWE for me to test, but all the `bera` package does is set the encoding to T1, load `beraserif`, `berasans` and `beramono`, and load `textcomp`. Since it was written in 2004, you no longer need `textcomp`; it’s now in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: Since you select `\ttfamily`, it should be sufficient to `\usepackage{beramono}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but you might be using a bit of `\berasans` too.

Comment: Alternatively, load `fontspec`, `\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}`, and `\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have amended my question with an MWE.

Comment: I just added the MWE, but your second answer helped out. If I added \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} it seems to have the proper font. It still feels like quite a struggle to do something as simple as change font, but I'm a LaTex newb I think so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pdf]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
     *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
      {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
      {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
      {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
      {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
      {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
      {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
      {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
      {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
      {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
      {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
      {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
      {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
      {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
      {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
      {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=json]
    {
      "type": "request-action",
      "content": {
        "id": 2,
        "time": 1556636930397,
        "deadline": 1556636934400,
        "step": 27,
        "percept": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Example of a REQUEST-ACTION message.}
    \label{fig:request-action}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This copies the lines from `bera.sty` that set the monospace fonts, but not the other fonts.  In particular, you want the T1, not the OT1, version of the font here.

If you can use a modern engine, you might do this instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pdf]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=Discretionary]

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
     *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
      {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
      {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
      {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
      {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
      {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
      {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
      {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
      {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
      {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
      {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
      {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
      {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
      {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
      {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
      {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=json]
    {
      "type": "request-action",
      "content": {
        "id": 2,
        "time": 1556636930397,
        "deadline": 1556636934400,
        "step": 27,
        "percept": {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Example of a REQUEST-ACTION message.}
    \label{fig:request-action}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: DejaVu Sans Mono sample]

This uses more modern extensions of the same fonts.

Answer (score 1):

It also works without `fontenc` if you use the `\usepackage{bera}`. Then you have the bera serif  and bera mono included:

```
name                       type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
-------------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZLEWRA+BeraSerif-Roman     Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
GTZSIU+BeraSansMono-Roman  Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
```

Comment: If you look at update 2, using `\usepackage{bera}` it also changes the rest of the text in my document. Which is not what I want, or do  you mean something else?

Comment: Then I misunderstood your problem and, of course, a simple `\usepackage{beramono}` will use only the mono font and leave the other families as is.